# Getting Blank columns in Excel file created through JAVA in Spring Frameworks(REST API)

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-mvc

I am having some problems while creating an excel file. I am using Spring frameworks and Rest API. My procedure is as follows:

1:Getting a DataList from SQL.
2: In the DataList, I have two dates; the StartDate and the EndDate. I extract the data that is present between these two dates.

The problem:
While i can successfully retrieve the data for first two rows, the third row shows incomplete data. I get only first few columns, and the rest are just blank. I am assuming this could be because i have a column named CreatedDate, where the date in 2 rows is 2017-09-24 14:13 and 2017-09-19 14:33. Again, I am not sure if this is causing the error.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet Sheet=workbook.createSheet("List Order Details");
        Row rowHeading=Sheet.createRow(0);
         rowHeading.createCell(0).setCellValue("Invoice ID");
         rowHeading.createCell(1).setCellValue("Food Court Name");
         rowHeading.createCell(2).setCellValue("Food Stall Name");
         rowHeading.createCell(3).setCellValue("Customer Name");
         rowHeading.createCell(4).setCellValue("Total Price");
         rowHeading.createCell(5).setCellValue("order status");
         rowHeading.createCell(6).setCellValue("Delivery Location");
         rowHeading.createCell(7).setCellValue("Delivery Date");
         rowHeading.createCell(8).setCellValue("Delivery Time");
         for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
             CellStyle stylerrowHeading=workbook.createCellStyle();
             HSSFFont font=workbook.createFont();
             font.setBold(true);
             font.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
             font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)11);
             stylerrowHeading.setFont(font);
             stylerrowHeading.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
            rowHeading.getCell(i).setCellStyle( stylerrowHeading);
            }
            if (null == excelList)
                  return null;
            int r=1;
        Row row=Sheet.createRow(r++);
                //id coloumn
                Cell cellId=(Cell) row.createCell(0);
                orderDO.setId(String.valueOf(orderEntity.getId()));
                cellId.setCellValue(""+orderEntity.getId());
                 r++;

                //foodstall name
                 Cell cellStallName=(Cell) row.createCell(2);
                cellStallName.setCellValue(foodStallEntity.getName());
                r++;
                //foodCourtname
                Cell cellCourtName=(Cell) row.createCell(1);
                 cellCourtName.setCellValue(foodCourtEntity.getName());
                //customername
                Cell cellCustomerName=(Cell) row.createCell(3);
            cellCustomerName.setCellValue(customerEntity.getName());
                r++;
                //total price
                Cell cellTotalPrice=(Cell) row.createCell(4);
                                     CellStyle styleprice=workbook.createCellStyle();
                 HSSFDataFormat cf=workbook.createDataFormat();
                 styleprice.setDataFormat(cf.getFormat(" $#,##0.00"));
                 cellTotalPrice.setCellStyle(styleprice);
                //orderstatus
                Cell cellOrderStatus=(Cell) row.createCell(5);
                orderDO.setStatus(OrderStatusDTO.valueOf(orderEntity.getOrderstatus()));
                 cellOrderStatus.setCellValue(orderEntity.getOrderstatus());

                //deliveryLocation
                Cell cellBuilding=(Cell) row.createCell(6);
                DeliveryLocationEntity deliveryLocationEntity = deliveryLocationRepository
                        .findById(orderEntity.getDeliverylocationid());
                orderDO.setDeliveryBuilding(deliveryLocationEntity.getBuilding());
              cellBuilding.setCellValue(deliveryLocationEntity.getBuilding());

                //deliverydate
                Cell cellDeliveryDate=(Cell) row.createCell(7);
                String s1 = String.valueOf(orderEntity.getOrderDate());
                orderDO.setOrderDate(s1.substring(0, 10));

                cellDeliveryDate.setCellValue(orderEntity.getOrderDate());
                 CellStyle styleCreationDate=workbook.createCellStyle();
                 HSSFDataFormat dfCreationDate=workbook.createDataFormat();
                 styleCreationDate.setDataFormat(dfCreationDate.getFormat(" m/d/yy"));
                 cellDeliveryDate.setCellStyle(styleCreationDate);

                //deliverytime
                Cell cellDeliveryTime=(Cell) row.createCell(8);
                orderDO.setDeliveryTime(orderEntity.getDeliverytime());
                cellDeliveryTime.setCellValue(orderEntity.getDeliverytime());

                for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
                Sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
                        FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(new File("attachment; filename=listproducts.xls"));
                        //response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=listproducts.xls");
                        workbook.write(out);
                        out.close();
                        workbook.close();
                        System.out.println("data enter Sucessfully...");



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return workbook;

}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code? The snippet you posted seems incomplete

Comment: i can'nt share whole java file for this now there is only two methods after this that is i am getting data from bean class and setting it into  setCellValue() after this saving the generated file at a location can you tell me what  property i add to remove gaps between two rows

Comment: In short no i can't. In the code posted above I only see that you call `createRow` only once, hence this code is only for the headers I suppose. You have to share more code to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe this part of your code:

```
int r=1;
for (OrderEntity orderEntity : excelList) {
    Row row=Sheet.createRow(r++);
    // more code
    r++;
    // more code
    r++;
    // more code
    r++;
    // more code
    r++;
    // more code
    r++;
}
```

you are increasing the `r` variable by calling `r++;` far too many times for no apparent reason. So the first time it is used in the `Sheet.createRow(r++);` call it has value `1`, it then gets increased 6 (or more, the end of the for loop is missing) times before the `createRow(r++)` is called again for the next row. This `r++` I think is not needed, you should remove these calls.

However your code still looks incomplete so I do not know if my answer will completely solve your problem. I cannot see where your `for` loop ends so there may be some more `r++` somewhere.

Comment: Dear sir yes this code works this only removes the space between two rows but now the problem is i am not getting details of last date and getting list of two entries in sql is in good format complete date but after third entry not getting complete data and enddate data

Comment: You do realize that you have posted incomplete code right? In your posted code you fill until cell number 4 `Cell cellTotalPrice=(Cell) row.createCell(4);` which is the "Total Price" column in your xls. For the columns after "Total Price", there is not a single line of code in your question. So nobody can help you to find out why it doesnt work.

Comment: You didn't post anything in your code! At least I cannot spot any change in the code part. Why you stopped posting code after cell number 4, `row.createCell(4)`. There must be some code for the other cells, 5,6,7,8 and 7,8 are the cells about the dates you are having problems. So post the code parts where you call `row.createCell(7)` or `row.createCell(8)`.

Comment: Are you sure the 3rd record in your Database has the relevant data? Can you upload a picture of the database table with the rows or else just put some `system.out.println(s1);` after `String s1 = String.valueOf(orderEntity.getOrderDate());` and post the console output

Comment: You have an error in the order_status column "RECIEVED" instead of "RECEIVED" and your `OrderStatusDTO` is enumeration. So this probably this line `OrderStatusDTO.valueOf(orderEntity.getOrderstatus())` throws an error! Correct the entry in the database and it should work ok. However it is very strange that you didn't see any errors in your application logs (or console as I see in your `try-catch` block), if you had posted them as well, we would have found the error easier and quicker

Comment: one last thing is not getting enddate like i am finding data between startdate=2017-09-19&endDate=2017-09-22 but not getting list of enddate